# How to monitor the CPU time of a running process in a period of time(Linux)?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I would like to measure the CPU usage of a running database server when I execute a query.
The goal is to get the wallclock time, total CPU time, user CPU time and kernel(system) CPU time, so I can estimate how much time is spent on computation, and how much time is on I/O.

The server is dedicated to this experiment and the CPU usage is close to 0% when no query is running, so my plan is to

1. start the monitor
2. run the query
3. stop the monitor and collect the CPU usage during the interval

The monitor can either give a sum of CPU time in that period or a list of sampling results, which I can sum them up myself.

I have searched for similar problems and tried several solutions but they do not satisfy my need.

1. `pidstat` pidstat seems good but the granularity is too coarse. The smallest interval is 1 second and I will need a finer interval such as 100ms.
2. `mpstat` The same problem as pidstat. Large interval.
3. `top` top can run in batch mode but the sampling interval is also big (2s-3s). It also does not provide user/kernel time breakdown.

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: You should see on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and/or linux admin forums

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "time" or "times" command. You might have to make some workaround to use these commands.

time program_name

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

"times" needs to be executed from the same shell from where database server has been started.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html

Comment: Elaborating on this answer, your command should look like something like this: `time psql -f file_with_sql.sql`